# Invalid aggregation name. Aggregation names must be alpha-numeric and can only contain '_' and '-'"

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, numeric, alphanumeric

I'm trying to use bucket selection with over an aggregation whose name contains numerical characters. **Invalid aggregation name [secondagg_sum_[filters_equals_100]]. Aggregation names must be alpha-numeric and can only contain '_' and '-'"** error has been occurred for me. I realized that aggregations with numeric characters has been solved but I think there is still an error for bucket selection. I asked the question on elastic search forum but nobody is replied. Is there anybody how to solve this problem?

PS: I'm generating my aggregation name dynamically so I need to use numeric characters.

Error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "Invalid aggregation name [secondagg_sum_[filters_equals_100]]. Aggregation names must be alpha-numeric and can only contain '_' and '-'",
        "line" : 1,
        "col" : 318
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "Invalid aggregation name [secondagg_sum_[filters_equals_100]]. Aggregation names must be alpha-numeric and can only contain '_' and '-'",
    "line" : 1,
    "col" : 318
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

My query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "disable_coord": false,
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1.0
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "first_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "firstproperty",
        "size": 2147483647,
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
        "order": {
          "_term": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "secondagg_sum_[filters_equals_100]": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "secondproperty"
          }
        },
        "agg_values": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "total": "secondagg_sum_[filters_equals_100]"
            },
            "script": {
              "inline": "params.total > 100",
              "lang": "painless"
            },
            "gap_policy": "skip"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In your aggregation names, you cannot have `[` or `]`

Comment: my mistake, thank you!

Comment: Why not @Val , what's wrong with having square brackets?

Comment: @JaiSharma because the error says so: `Aggregation names must be alpha-numeric and can only contain '_' and '-'` :-)

Comment: I see that. Is there a particular reason ES restricts use of square brackets in aggregations? Is there a way to escape such chars?